Unable to access People API in a spreadsheet app script
I am trying to connect my google form response sheet to create a new contact using details every time a response is submitted on the form. I've added Peopleapi from the "Services" tab in the apps script. I've also created the credentials for the people api  from google console from the same account and I've also called for api access token. Still I am getting the error
ReferenceError: PeopleApi is not defined 


Refer the complete code below :
var apiKey = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  PeopleApi.getService().setToken(apiKey);


function onFormSubmit() {

  
  // Get data from spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var name = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
  var phone = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
  var address = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 4, 1, 1).getValue();
  

  // Create a People API service object
  var peopleService = PeopleApi.getService();

  // Build the person resource
  var person = {
    names: [{
      givenName: name
    }],
  
    addresses: [{
      formattedValue: address,
      type: "home"
    }],
    phoneNumbers: [{
      value: phone,
      type: "mobile"
    }],
    metadata: {
      primary: true
    }
  };

 

  // Create the contact using the People API
  peopleService.people().createContact(person).execute();
}

I've added Peopleapi from the "Services" tab in the apps script. I've also created the credentials for the people api  from google console from the same account and I've also called for api access token.

What is PeopleApi? Is it your library? From var apiKey = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() and PeopleApi.getService().setToken(apiKey), it seems that you use People API with the access token retrieved by OAuth2. If you are not required to use PeopleApi, how about using People API with Advanced Google services? You can see the sample scripts about it at here. But, if this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

@Tanaike The OP said: ". I've added Peopleapi from the "Services" tab in the apps script. ," Probably the Is a mistake on the Services name.

Thankyou for responding, I've discovered that the people api is accessible without the OAuth but I'm not sure what is wrong with the code or syntax as whenever there's mention of people api:
// Create a People API service object
var peopleService = PeopleApi.getService();
and
// Create the contact using the People API
People.people.createContact(person).execute();
I'm getting the error : "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined"

@Wicket Thank you for your comment. From execute() of peopleService.people().createContact(person).execute() in the showing script, I guessed that OP wanted to use the originally created script. So, I mentioned about it. But, if OP just misunderstands the People API of Advanced Google services, I believe that your answer will lead in the correct direction.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The default identifier for the Peopleapi Service is People.

You should double-check what is the identifier set for this Service in your Google Apps Script project. For this, look at the corresponding item below the Services section

In the above image, the item for the Peopleapi is  People. Clicking on this item will show a dialog to change the Service settings, including the identifier.
Most Google Apps Script users will keep the default identifier name, so I suggest you keep it, too.

On the other hand, getService() is not a method of Peopleapi.

I wonder if you have written the code from scratch or used a tool to generate it. When using code generation tools, it's highly recommended to spend some time learning the basics of the IDE, programming language and services that you will use to be able to identify if the the code generation tool is giving helpful something. Please remember that tools like ChatGPT might have AI hallucinations.
Related

add a created contact to a group by people api using google apps script

